# Display checkbox in QGIS composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I created an atlas in composer with my results from site visit forms.

I would like to display a checkbox with ticked or unticked state depending on my field value.

I am thinking as a workaround to use two svg files which are displayed or not depending the field value, but it is a bit complicated when multiplicating the fields.

Is there an easier way to do so?

Comment: Some fonts ([like Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings)) have a checkbox checked (1F5F7) and unchecked (1F78E). You can after display the wanted character with an expression and a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Many thanks it works ! However for me I just use 'r' for unticked box and 'x' for ticked box (with azerty keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

Answer as described in comments by J. Monticolo:

Some fonts (like Wingdings) have a checkbox checked (1F5F7) and unchecked (1F78E). You can after display the wanted character with an expression and a CASE statement.